# Sugar CRM, Create a role only to view, update but not create a record

Tags: permissions, edit, roles, sugarcrm

I have few agents who will be working on some leads. Here, I want them to view the record, update them with the info they got over the call but not create a new record.

I tried everything.I disabled 'edit' role.now they can neither create a record nor update it..

All I want is agent can view, update but not create.

Hope I made myself clear on this issue...Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Vaseem.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is no such `role` which allows only `update` with no `insertion`.

However the scenario can only be handled through coding. You can add before save logic hook and can avoid saving the record if the user is not on a specific role and the record is new. More hide the create button from menu depending on the role.

Answer (score 0):

You may extend Menu.php and keep "Create Lead" conditionally. If user is agent(considering you have something to identify user's role) dont show "Create Lead".

Like wise in subpanel too!